# Use Struts2 property tag in DisplayTags

Tags: struts2, displaytag

I'm trying to render a table using DisplayTag. Everything works normally when I render a column in the usual manner:

```
<display:column property="id_material" title="ID" />
```

Now, i want one column to show 2 properties concatenated. So I tried using the < s:property > tag:

```
<display:column title="UNIDAD"><s:property value="property1"/> <s:property value="property2"/></display:column>
```

But no value is showed in the column. Is there an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a decorator, get the row object properties and return the concatenation of both.

A quick example:

```
    public class ExampleDecorator extends TableDecorator{

    public String getConcatenatedProperties(){

    Object object = getCurrentRowObject();
    return object.getProperty1() + " " + getProperty2();

}}
```

Then you add a column in the display table:

```
<display:column property="concatenatedProperties" title="Properties" />
```

To use the decorator in the displaytag:

```
<display:table [..]  decorator="org.example.ExampleDecorator" [...] >
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add uid attribute in table tag and then you can access current row in Struts2 via request attribute. See following code:

```
<display:table name="list" uid="row">
    <display:column title="UNIDAD"><s:property value="#attr.row.property1"/>    <s:property value="#attr.row.property2"/>
    </display:column>
</display:table>
```